# Python List ONLY the variables I have created

Tags: python, variables

I have run my Python script that created `22` variables according to `%whos` IPython command.

I want to be able to list MY variables from within a Python (not IPython) script.

So far, I tried `dir()`, `vars().keys()`, `locals().keys()` and `globals().keys()` :

```
In [2]: len( [v for v in dir() if not v.startswith('_')] )
Out[2]: 1015

In [3]: len( [v for v in vars().keys() if not v.startswith('_')] )
Out[3]: 1015

In [4]: len( [v for v in locals().keys() if not v.startswith('_')] )
Out[4]: 1015

In [5]: len( [v for v in globals().keys() if not v.startswith('_')] )
Out[5]: 1015
```

I ONLY want MY variables that I created, how can I do that ?

Comment: Then you need to define a better prefix than `'_'` .. maybe `_myvar_`

Comment: @Vinny Is there no other way ? How does the IPython `%whos` do the job ?

Comment: IPython `%whos` displays variable name, type and data of user variables (removing non-user variables from `locals()`).

Comment: @Austin Sure, but how does `%whos` recognize non-user variables ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can keep track of the original ones before declaring:

```
orig_keys = set(globals().keys())
a = 10
b = 100
c = 1000
my_keys = set(globals().keys()) - orig_keys
print(my_keys)
```

Results in:

```
{'orig_keys', 'a', 'c', 'b'}
```

You can check it [live here](https://repl.it/repls/InfiniteChartreuseMetric)